# Animatin :before element that is inside hovered div

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Ive got some problems with animating :before element. It's a little bit messy but im leaving it at stage that i ended my job. So everytinhgs work beside that :before element - arrow in FA. It should smoothly slide to right side, but its only jumping eaven with transition time seted up.

HTML and CSS:

```css
.seemore span {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  left: -90px;
  width: 10px !important;
}

.seemore {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}

.usluga:hover {
  background: #dc0d1d;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}

.seemore:hover,
.seemore:focus {
  /* things won't work in IE 10 without this declaration */
}

.usluga:hover .normalfont,
.usluga:hover .headerfont,
.usluga:hover .seemore:before {
  color: white !important;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}

.usluga:hover .seemore span {
  left: 0px;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}

.seemore:before {
  content: " ";
  background: red;
  widows: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  color: #dc0d1d;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  position: absolute;
}

.usluga:hover .seemore:before {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.usluga:hover .seemore:before {
  left: 130px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="usluga">
  <p class="headerfont" style="padding-bottom: 0.1em;">01<span class="smallfont"> / print</span></p>
  <p class="normalfont">Druk<br>Wielkoformatowy</p>
  <p class="seemore"><span>zobacz więcej</span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Transition goes from initial value to a new value and bounces back.

You do not have an initial `left` property set for your element.

Just add `left: 0` to the initial stats and it should work.

```css
.seemore span {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  left: -90px;
  width: 10px !important;
}

.seemore {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}

.usluga:hover {
  background: #dc0d1d;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}

.seemore:hover,
.seemore:focus {
  /* things won't work in IE 10 without this declaration */
}

.usluga:hover .normalfont,
.usluga:hover .headerfont,
.usluga:hover .seemore:before {
  color: white !important;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}

.usluga:hover .seemore span {
  left: 0px;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}

.seemore:before {
  content: " ";
  background: red;
  widows: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  color: #dc0d1d;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  position: absolute;
  /* Setting initial 'left' value */
  left: 0;
}

.usluga:hover .seemore:before {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.usluga:hover .seemore:before {
  left: 130px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="usluga">
  <p class="headerfont" style="padding-bottom: 0.1em;">01<span class="smallfont"> / print</span></p>
  <p class="normalfont">Druk<br>Wielkoformatowy</p>
  <p class="seemore"><span>zobacz więcej</span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah...i missed that - preety simple "debugging" stuff that's not hard programming. Thank You ;)